# SLSQP Minimisation method rely on the initial geuss

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I try to minimize a function with multiple variable using scipy. optimise. 
The minimisation is not done a proper way because

```
  def f(p):
A=np.zeros(c)
for i in range(c):
    A [i]= (f_i[i] - (p[0] * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(j[i], p[1], p[2]) + p[3]* scipy.stats.norm.pdf(j[i], p[4], p[5]) + p[6]* scipy.stats.norm.pdf(j[i], p[7], p[8])))**2
return sum(A[0:c])
def my_cons(p):
g = np.zeros(10)
g[0] =p[0]-0
g[1] =p[1]-0
g[2] =p[2]-0
g[3] =p[3]-0
g[4] =p[4]-0
g[5] =p[5]-0
g[6] =p[6]-0
g[7] =p[7]-0
g[8] =p[8]-0
g[9] = p[0]+p[3]+p[6]-1.
return g
cons= ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[0]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[1]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[2]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[3]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[4]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[5]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[6]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[7]-0},
   {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[8]-0},
   {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda p: p[0]+p[3]+p[6]-1})
x0 = np.array((0.1, 25., 6.1, 0.2, 35., 10.,0.1, 16., 10.))
res = optimize.minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP',jac=None, bounds=None, constraints=cons,tol=None,options={'disp': True ,'eps' : 1e-8, 'maxiter' : 1000})
print res
```

Where j and f_i are taken from an csv file. 
When I use the x0 mentioned above I obtain:

```
nfev: 23
nit: 2
njev: 2
status: 0
success: True

   x: array([  1.11173074e-19,   1.06811225e+01,   1.91022230e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   3.11982112e+01,   7.50048570e+01,
     1.94288182e-20,   3.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01])
```

when I use an other one for instance:

```
x0 = np.array([1.3, 10.7, 1.8, 21.9, 31.2,75,0.6,0.3,0.1])
```

I obtain:

```
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'

nfev: 23
nit: 2
njev: 2
status: 0
success: True

   x: array([  1.11173074e-19,   1.06811225e+01,   1.91022230e+00,
     1.00000000e+00,   3.11982112e+01,   7.50048570e+01,
     1.94288182e-20,   3.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01])
```

How to define a good initial geuss?
Am I using the wrong method?

Comment: I might miss something but the outputs you show look identical to me, so what is the actual problem? Also, could you fix your indentation!?

Comment: This has not much to do with python (which is mostly using the same code internally as matlab and co.). It's just a characteristic of possibly non-convex optimization (start-values are always important and the one who defined the problem should know best which are good and which are not). What kind of help do you expect here?

Comment: @ celib for x0 = np.array((0.0, 13., 9.1, 0.7, 27., 1.7,0.25, 39., 1.5))  i obtaoin  : [  0.75519843  13.00862389   9.09685564   0.11256798  27.252224,1.99542984   0.13223359  38.79412185   1.3473147 ] for an other geuss x0 = np.array((0.1, 25., 6.1, 0.2, 35., 10.,0.1, 16., 10.))    i obtain an other output  [  0.36413429  24.96882197   6.09752554   0.10973026  34.99441345, 10.01669139   0.52613545  15.99888224   9.98633836]; These outputs are clearly not the same.

Comment: @ sascha , I understand that it has somthing to do with the used method may be. What i'm looking for is a way to optimize the intial geuss. You cann look at the example i gave to @Celib, the minilmisation is unstable. I was wondering if is there an other method for solving this type of problem.

Comment: What is a _geuss_?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to fit a Gaussian mixture model. Instead of using the general purpose routines from `scipy.optimize` it might be better to take a look at scikit-learns `sklearn.mixture` (see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html), which was written for this exact purpose.

Staying with routines from `scipy.optimize`, there is one alternative algorithm that allows for constraints, called COBYLA, that you might want to try out. It does only allow for inequality constraints but you can simply redefine your problem to eliminate the equality constraint. This means you replace p[6] by 1-p[0]-p[3] and add the inequality constraint 1-p[0]-p[3] >= 0.